# How to invoke finish() individually on modules in omnet++

Tags: c++, omnet++

I am using Omnet++ and creating a scenario where a sender keeps sending packets to a receiver (uni-directional communication from sender to receiver) and I have set a counter on both the simple modules of sender and receiver.

Since the sender's counter counts down to zero first than the receiver, the simulation run well but it does not record statistics since all that is done at the receiver.

after the counter is decreased to zero both the modules invoke a `finish()` function.

```
sender::finish()
{
 EV << "message limit reached \n";
 cancelAndDelete(myEvent);
}
```

receiver's finish function:

```
void receiver::finish()
{
  EV << "mean:   "<< iatStats.getMean() << endl;
  EV << "std.dev:   " << iatStats.getStddev() << endl;
  EV << "variance:  " << iatStats.getVariance() << endl;

  iatStats.recordAs("Inter-Arrival Times");
  recordScalar("#IAT", interAT_diff);
}
```

here iat is calculation for inter-arrival time between the packets at the receiver.

After the simulation runs, the sender's `finish()` is invoked first and the simulation stops and no data is recorded in `/results` folder only blank `.vec` or `.sca` files exist.

also the terminal says `simulation fault: core dumped`

The problem is how can I "pause" the sender block once the counter is run out and let the receiver invoke it's `finish()` function so that I could see the stats and also record all the data I need?

Hope the description is clear enough.
Thanks

Comment: The message `simulation fault: core dumped` means that an **error** during simulation occurs. Try to debug your simulation to determine which instruction causes that error. Or present your whole code in your question.

Comment: found the glitch and posted the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that calling two finishes for individual modules isn't the right thing to.
hence, to tackle the situation I renamed the `finish()` function in the sender block to `done()`. This helps the simulator to provide a better functionality and the when the counter on the receiver comes to zero the `finish()` function is invoked and all the data collection occurs perfectly and it even gets displayed on the message console.

any other name instead of `finish()` needs to be used when using separate modules e.g. `stopBlock()` or `done()` or any generic name. Make sure that `finish()` is invoked **ONLY ONCE** in the complete simulation.

The reason is `finish()` function is for the complete Omnet++ environment and if any one block/module invokes it first the other modules will stop functioning.